# Error turning glass into light absorbent

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, modifiers

So I made a cup of coffee transparent:

[image: modeled cup]

but when I turned the liquid inside light absorption to make the coffee, the glass turned like metallic. And I don't know why. Here is the example without errors (https://youtu.be/fdWUjEMzDhg):

[image: cup of coffee from tutorial]

Thanks!

Comment: Don't make users go to links to understand your question.Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: If I remember right you have to scale the liquid down or up very slightly to get it to be visible through the glass.